# Does macOS keep a log of all access to the keychain?

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I want to see which applications accessed my keychain of my Mac. Do know which apps have access and how often they do. Does macOS keep a log of that somewhere ?

Comment: If you don't find a good answer, consider locking the keychain and then see when you're asked to unlock it. ProTip: you don't need to have your keychain password be the same as your account password. ProTip: you can store more sensitive entries in other keychains so you're prompted/secured by another passphrase if you desire.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to lock the keychain. Good idea. There is indeed an option for it. It then shows a small lock at the screen top. Then I was asked several times to unlock by processes that sound legit, but still I cancelled all. Even then after a while the lock showed unlocked. Strange. This happened several times. So in the end I just left in unlocked.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, on MacOS Sierra or newer you can monitor **every access** to the Keychain, using the Unified Logging system in two operation modes:

1. Realtime
2. Query the database log to get past access events

---

Use this command on a Terminal window for Realtime monitoring:

```
log stream --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.securityd" AND message CONTAINS[cd] "Keychain Access"' --info --debug --signpost --style compact
```

Here is the output of the above command, in realtime, while some keychain items were being accessed:

[image]

You can also query past events by specifying some date range, and changing `stream` to `show`. Like the example below:

```
log show --start "2019-08-11 14:21:45" --end "2019-08-11 14:22:00" --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.securityd" AND message CONTAINS[cd] "Keychain Access"' --info --debug --signpost --style compact
```

More detailed information can be obtained by modifying the command line and grouping other process interactions. See `man log` for more options, or just ask here :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't include applications accessing resources they stored in the keychain

Comment: I changed "Keychain Access" to "Keychain" and got some additional useful messages.